# Cloudera and Cdap integration

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cdap

How to add CDAP(cask data application platform) in cloudera? I installed cloudera in my machine and added a node to it. Now I want to add cdap to cloudera in my node using cloudera manager.

Comment: Hi Pablo, what version of Cloudera and CDAP do you use? And how stable is the setup? I am having stability and unexpected behavior issues on CDH 5.13 and CDAP 5.2.1. Thx for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to CDAP installation docs for Cloudera Manager here: https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/5.0.0/en/admin-manual/installation/cloudera.html and follow the installation steps.

Comment: Actually I got CDAP 3.6.0-1 distributed and activated on CDH 5.7.0, but when I try to add service I cannot see CDAP available for add. Do I have some version mismatch.